# Blocking dialog like construct in android

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

Looking for a blocking,value returning dialog like custom construct in android.

Something like this:

```
Output outValue = MyPopupBuildingClass.showWindow(inValue, R.layout.my_layout);
```

Yes that's the all too familiar `MessageBox` for `Windows programmers` :) and I think there is `JOptionPane` in Swing too.

The complexity here is that I don't want a small default android dialog, but more of a popup fragment with some detailed layout and functionality. It accepts an object, pops up a window, lets user do something to it and return it back when user accepts  or dismiss.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First, I'm not familiar with the Windows MessageBox dialog but... If you're trying to have a dialog which blocks the rest of the code execution until a value is returned from it(because it needs that value ), you should avoid this. An alternative would be to modify the code which depends on the returned value and use a callback system that notifies that portion of code when the popup fragment has returned something.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Also, I'm considering that a popup on android is involved with calling of `onPause()` of underlying activity etc. So it might be impossible to do blocking. But this feature would have made life easy.

Comment: A dialog will indeed pause the activity, but not if you just put a fragment on top of the current layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Luksprog said in comments, Blocking dialogs in android are hard to implement and should be avoided.